# Is a Rational Rotation Algebra a Cutdown of a Matrix Algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\theta=m/n$ and let $A_{\theta}$ be the rational rotation C$^{*}$-algebra with rotation angle $\theta$. I.e., $A_{\theta}=C^{*}(u,v)$, where $u$ and $v$ are unitaries such that $vu=e^{2\pi i \theta}uv$. I know from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3006477/why-is-the-rational-rotation-algebra-not-a-matrix-algebra) that $A_{\theta}$ is not a full matrix algebra. [Given](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3001658/what-are-the-irreducible-representations-of-the-rational-rotation-c-algebr) that $A_{\theta}$ has irreducible representations only of degree $n$, is it true that $A_{\theta}$ is a cutdown of a full matrix algebra? I.e.,

> Is there a space $C(X,M_{n}(\mathbb{C}))$ and a projection $p\in C(X,M_{n}(\mathbb{C}))$, such that $A_{\theta}$ is isomorphic to $pC(X,M_{n}(\mathbb{C}))p$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

As $\theta$ is rational, it follows that $A_{\theta}$ is Morita equivalent to $C(\mathbb{T}^2)$, see for example [The classification of rational rotation algebras- Brabanter.](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01193614.pdf)

However, two unital $C^*$-algebras are Morita equivalent if and only if each  is a full corner of $n\times n$ matrices over the other, for some $n$, see [$C^*$-algebras associated with irrational rotations- Rieffel, Proposition 2.1](https://www.univie.ac.at/nuhag-php/bibtex/open_files/ri81_Rieffel-IrrRot.pdf).

Thus $A_{m/n}\cong pM_k(C(\mathbb{T}^2))p$, for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and full prjection $p\in M_k(C(\mathbb{T}^2))$.